# How to configure Traefik Sticy Session in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, load-balancing, traefik, traefik-ingress

I am merging my applications from `docker` to `kubernetes`.

I am currently working with `minikube`.

I am using traefik as my reverse proxy, and it was installed in kubernetes using the oficial `helm chart` available at https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart.

Here is my working docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3.7"
services:
  myapp:
    image: nexus/my-app
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.rule=Host(`myapp.localhost`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.entrypoints=web,web-secure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapp.service=myapp"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.myapp.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.myapp.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.sticky=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.sticky.cookie.name=StickyCookieMyApp"
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.sticky.cookie.secure=true"
      # enable the property below if your are running on https
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https"      
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
```

In Kubernetes I have the following configuration that is working:

```yaml
# HTTPS ingress
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myapp.localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: myapp
              servicePort: 8080
  tls:
    - secretName: myapp-cert
---
# Ingresses
# this middleware is used as the following annotation:
# traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: default-redirect@kubernetescrd
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: redirect
spec:
  redirectScheme:
    scheme: https
    permanent: true
---
# http ingress for http->https redirection
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: myapp-redirect
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: default-redirect@kubernetescrd
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myapp.localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: myapp
              servicePort: 8080
```

How do I transform these three lines into Kubernetes spec?

```yaml
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.sticky=true"
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.sticky.cookie.name=StickyCookieMyApp"
      - "traefik.http.services.myapp.loadbalancer.sticky.cookie.secure=true"
```

Answer (score 4):

You would set annotations on your service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service.sticky.cookie: "true"
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service.sticky.cookie.name: cookie
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service.sticky.cookie.secure: "true"
[...]
```

See docs: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-ingress/

Comment: Thank you for your reply @SYN. I wander why the traefik team doesn't add simple examples like this on their documentation. It would make life much easier.